# Calculation of $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x-1+\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x+1+\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Calculation of $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x-1+\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x+1+\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $x=\tan \psi\;,$ Then $\displaystyle dx = \sec^2 \psi$

So Integral convert into $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\tan \psi-1+\sec \psi}{\tan \psi+1+\sec \psi}d\psi = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\tan \psi+\sec \psi - 1}{\tan \psi+\sec \psi+1}d\psi$

Now Multiply both Numerator and Denominator by $\left(\tan \psi+\sec \psi-1\right)$

So $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\tan \psi+\sec \psi-1}{\tan \psi+\sec \psi+1} \times \frac{\tan \psi+\sec \psi-1}{\tan \psi+\sec \psi-1}d\psi = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\left(\tan \psi+\sec \psi-1\right)^2}{\left(\tan \psi+\sec \psi\right)^2-1}d\psi$

Now I did not understand how can i solve after that

Help required

Thanks.

Comment: How about starting with the initial integral and expanding the fraction by $1+x -\sqrt{1+x^2}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting $x=\tan2y$  $$F=\frac{\tan2y+\sec2y-1}{\tan2y+\sec2y+1}=\frac{\sin2y+1-\cos2y}{\sin2y+1+\cos2y}$$

Using Double Angle formula,  $$F=\frac{2\sin y\cos y+2\sin^2y}{2\sin y\cos y+2\cos^2y}=\frac{2\sin y(\cos y+\sin y)}{2\cos y(\sin y+\cos y)}=\tan y$$ assuming  $\cos y+\sin y\ne0\iff\tan y\ne-1\implies x=\tan2y\ne\infty$

Answer (score 9):

**Hint**

As suggested by Fabian, multiply both numerator and denominator by $1+x -\sqrt{1+x^2}$. After simplfication, you should arrive to $$\frac{x-1+\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x+1+\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}-1}{x}$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 7):

Solution:

Let $$t=x+1+\sqrt{1+x^2}\to 1+x^2=(t-1-x)^2\to x=\frac{t^2-2t}{2t-2}\to dx=\frac{t^2-2t+2}{2(t-1)^2}dt$$

We have $$x-1+\sqrt{1+x^2}=t-2$$

And $$\frac{x-1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x+1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\frac{t-2}{t}$$

Hence $$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x-1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x+1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx=\int_{2}^{2+\sqrt{2}}\frac{t-2}{t}\frac{t^2-2t+2}{2(t-1)^2}dt$$

$$=\int_{2}^{2+\sqrt{2}}\left[\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2}{t}+\frac{1}{t-1}-\frac{1}{2(t-1)^2}\right]dt=\cdots$$

Answer (score 4):

Substitute $x=\sqrt{y^2-1}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x-1+\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x+1+\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx
=\int_1^{\sqrt2}\frac y{1+y}dy=\sqrt2-1+\ln[2(\sqrt2-1)]
\end{align}

Comment: What a wonderful substitution!

Answer (score 3):

After multiplying the integrand with $1+x-\sqrt{1+x^2}$, then you may use [Euler substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution) to evaluate the integral.
For further learning, you may refer to this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/758247/123277). The integral in the given link *almost* similar with yours, perhaps yours is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Letting $x=\tan \theta$ gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{x-1+\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x+1+\sqrt{x^2+1}} &=\frac{\tan \theta-1+\sec \theta}{\tan \theta+1+\sec \theta} \\
&=\frac{\sin \theta-\cos \theta+1}{\sin \theta+\cos \theta+1} \\
&=\frac{2 \sin \frac{\theta}{2} \cos \frac{\theta}{2}+2 \sin ^2 \frac{\theta}{2}}{2 \sin \frac{\theta}{2} \cos \frac{\theta}{2}+2 \cos ^2 \frac{\theta}{2}} \\
&=\frac{\sin \frac{\theta}{2}}{\cos \frac{\theta}{2} }=\frac{\sin \theta}{1+\cos \theta}
\end{aligned}
$$
Then let $c=\cos \theta,$ we have$$
I= -\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}  } \frac{d c}{(1+c) c^2}= \int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\left(\frac{1}{c}-\frac{1}{c^2}-\frac{1}{1+c}\right) d c= \sqrt{2}-1+\ln [2(\sqrt{2}-1)]
$$