# Integral $\int \sqrt{x^2-3x+2}\ dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

How to evaluate $$\int_3^{17} \sqrt{x^2-3x+2}\ dx \ ?$$ I tried Euler's substitution, that is $$\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}=x+t \Longleftrightarrow \frac{t^2-2}{-3-2t}+t=\frac{t^2+3t+2}{2t+3}\ ,$$ which I obtained from $$x^2+2tx+t^2=x^2-3x+2\Longleftrightarrow x=\frac{t^2-2}{-3-2t}$$ $$dx=\frac{2t(-3-2t)-(t^2-2)(-2)}{(-3-2t)^2}\ dt=-\frac{2t^2+6t+4}{(3+2t)^2} \ dt\ .$$ $x\in[3,17]$, so $t\in[\sqrt{2}-3,\sqrt{240}-17]$ (right?). Then we got $$\int_{\sqrt{2}-3}^{\sqrt{240}-17} \frac{t^2+3t+2}{2t+3}(-\frac{2t^2+6t+4}{(2t+3)^2})\ dt=-2\int_{\sqrt{2}-3}^{\sqrt{240}-17} \frac{(t^2+3t+2)^2}{(2t+3)^3}\ dt$$ and it's where I stuck...

## EDIT

Ok I finished it my way, but I've heard there's a possibility to do it using $(x-\frac{3}{2})=\tan (t)$ substitution. How exactly?

Comment: Why use such a complicated approach? This can be easily handled with a trig substitution after a little manipulation.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but since I got this far, I'd like to know if I got everything right. And how to finish.

Comment: Although it's complicated, it's still correct. Next you can use [partial fractions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+fractions+%5Cfrac%7B%28t%5E2%2B3t%2B2%29%5E2%7D%7B%282t%2B3%29%5E3%7D).

Comment: You may also want to take a look [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/758247/123277) for learning another integral that uses Euler's substitution.

Comment: You sure it's right? I put it in Wolfram and [got this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+3%2F16%2Bt%2F8%2B1%2F%2816+%283%2B2+t%29^3%29-1%2F%288+%283%2B2+t%29%29+from+sqrt%282%29-3+to+sqrt%28240%29+-17), but should get [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+sqrt%28x^2-3x%2B2%29+from+3+to+17)

Comment: " $x\in[3,17]$, so $t\in[\sqrt{2}-3,\sqrt{240}-17]$ (right?). "  Unless it's the other set of solutions to your rational function, with $ \ x \ = \ 3 \ $ corresponding to $ \ t \ = \ -(3 + \sqrt{2}) \ $ and $ \ x \ = \ 17 \ $ , to $ \ t \ = \ -(17 + \sqrt{240}) \ $ .  The rational function for $ \ x \ $ is not one-to-one...

Comment: OK, it turns out that it doesn't matter which interval in $ \ t \ $ you use.  You _do_ have the right result: don't forget that you entered into WA your integral in $ \ t \ $ _alone_ in your first link, but the _original_ integral into WA for your second link. But $ \ (-2) \cdot (-59.35...) \ $ _is_ 118.70...  [Though, as noted in the answers below, there are easier ways to get there.]

Comment: Oh, shoot, I didn't notice the $-2$ term. That explains a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

I think that you made your life very complicated.

If I may suggest, start completing the square $$x^2-3x+2=\Big(x-\frac{3}{2}\Big)^2-\frac {9}{4}+2=\Big(x-\frac{3}{2}\Big)^2-\frac {1}{4}$$ and now change variable such $$x-\frac{3}{2}= \frac{1}{2}\cosh(y)$$ You will arrive to something very simple for the integrand and then for the antiderivative.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Which has the huge advantage of being a *logical* approach, hence an easy one to remember and to implement in related cases. +1.

Answer (score 0):

An Euler Substitution will work, remember that there are several such substitutions and you have the root of a quadratic which factors. Another approach in addition to the excellent idea above is to write the integral as
$$\int (x-1)\sqrt{\frac{x-2}{x-1}}$$
and let 
$$y^2=\frac{x-2}{x-1}$$